# Why CityBlock(Manhattan Distance) values are different in scipy.spatial.distance.pdist and sklearn.metric.pairwise_distances

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, scipy-spatial

To solve a problem I need manhattan distances between all the vectors. I tried `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` but the size was too large, so in order to decrease memory footprint I used `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to get the condensed `1D` matrix of distances.

I used below formula:

```
index = diagonalShape*(diagonalShape-1)/2 - (diagonalShape-i)*(diagonalShape-i-1)/2 + j - i - 1
```

to calculate the index of the `1D` matrix to get the distance value of `ij`.

I've observed that for many entries the distances are different form `scipy` and `sklearn`. Why this is so when the formula used for calculating cityblock distances is same for both the libraries?

Comment: Please post some specific examples of data where, as you say, the results are different.